# Millisecond timing C++

Tags: c++, time

I want to time the real-time performance of some C++ functions I have written. How do I get the timing in milliseconds scale?

I know how to get time in seconds via

```
start=clock()
diff=(clock()-start)/(double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC
cout<<diff
```

I am using Ubuntu-Linux OS and g++ compiler.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sub-millisecond precision timing in C or C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904887/sub-millisecond-precision-timing-in-c-or-c)

Comment: It is impressive how many questions ask this same lately using `clock()`. To measure time you should be using `gettimeofday()` or `clock_gettime()`.

Comment: ^ I think there's a newer, better alternative than gettimeofday(), clock_gettime()... mentioned by Ethereal below. I was surprised that gettimeofday() is on the way out, too.

Comment: Not to be a total sourpuss, but why is this getting upvotes? As pointed out, this question has been asked plenty of times before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Linux, take a look at `clock_gettime()`. It can essentially give you the time elapsed since an arbitrary point, in nanoseconds (which should be good enough for you).

Note that it *is* specified by the POSIX standard, so you should be fine using it on Unix-derived systems.

Comment: +1, specifically, [clock_gettime()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_getres.html) with `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID` would be a replacement for `clock()`

Comment: @Jerry Coffin You are correct, of course, but OP did say they are using Linux, which had CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID and CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID since 1994, it seems.

Comment: @Cubbi: oops -- I didn't read quite as far down in the question as I should have, and missed the reference to using Linux. My mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Try diff = (clock() - start) * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

The idea is that you multiply the number of clocks by 1000, so that whereas before you might get 2 (seconds), you now get 2000 (milliseconds).

Answer (score 0):

Notes:

On my Dell desktop, which is reasonably quick ... 
ubuntu bogomips peak at 5210

time(0) takes about 80 nano-seconds (30 million calls in 2.4 seconds)

time(0) allows me to measure
   clock_gettime() which takes about 1.3 u-seconds per call (2.2 million in 3 seconds)
(I don't remember how many nano-seconds per time step)

So typically, I use the following, with about 3 seconds of invocations.

```
// ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////        
void measuring_something_duration()                        
...            
uint64_t   start_us = dtb::get_system_microsecond();  
do_something_for_about_3_seconds()      
uint64_t test_duration_us = dtb::get_system_microsecond() - start_us;    

uint64_t test_duration_ms = test_duration_us / 1000;
...
```

which use these functions

```
// /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////   
uint64_t mynamespace::get_system_microsecond(void)  
{  
   uint64_t total_ns = dtb::get_system_nanosecond();   // see below   
   uint64_t ret_val = total_ns / NSPUS;     // NanoSecondsPerMicroSeconds     
   return(ret_val);   
}


// /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  
uint64_t mynamespace::get_system_nanosecond(void)  
{  
   //struct timespec {  __time_t tv_sec;    long int tv_nsec;  };  -- total 8 bytes  
   struct timespec ts;

   // CLOCK_REALTIME - system wide real time clock   
   int status = clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);   
   dtb_assert(0 == status);   

   // to 8 byte     from   4 byte   
   uint64_t uli_nsec = ts.tv_nsec;   
   uint64_t uli_sec  = ts.tv_sec;   

   uint64_t total_ns = uli_nsec + (uli_sec * NSPS); // nano-seconds-per-second    

   return(total_ns);   
}
```

Remember to link  -lrt